# MySQL PHP syntax when trying to update a duplicate column's row

Tags: php, mysql

**Desired behavior:** I have a form that is designed to take data and put it into a mySQL table. The desired outcome is to have users enter their data, and if one submission in a particular column is submitted, the new data for the entire row will overwrite the old data.

**Current behavior:** I am getting a syntax error when the form is submitted.

**Preliminary notes:** I realize this code has potential for injection but the form consists only of dropdowns and a date picker (no open fields). Plus, this will be used for a very small organization with very little tech savvy.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable (library, reason, closedate, opendate) VALUES 
('$library', '$reason', '$closedate', '$opendate')
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reason=$reason(reason), 
closeDate=$closedate(closedate), openDate=$opendate(opendate)";
```

**Error message:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'weather. (reason), closeDate=2018-07-18(closedate), openDate=2018-07-27(opendate' at line 2

**Attempts to correct syntax:** I have tried separating all of my ON DUPLICATE KEY parameters by parenthesis, apostrophes and both at the same time. I have also tried removing what is currently displayed in parenthesis out, because I have seen successful code work both ways.

I would really appreciate any suggestions, thank you!

Comment: [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will help you solve your problems. In other words, use prepared statements and you won't have to worry about the problem you're facing ever again (or, at least, part of it)

Comment: What the.... `" .... reason=$reason(reason) .... "` ?? Is that supposed to be a php variable of just `$reason` or a php anonymous function of `$reason(reason)` where `reason` is some constant? Also, since all of that is buried in double quotes, its going to cause issues if its not just `$reason` you want inserted into the statement, especially since they are all missing single quotes. And on top of all of this, yes... just use `prepare` and probably all your problems will go away.

Comment: Same answer as in your Reddit-post: Your table name and columns within the update-part are not escaped. Also this is one of the most insecure commands I have ever seen

Comment: What you probably want is `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reason=VALUES(reason), closedate=VALUES(closedate), opendate=VALUES(opendate)`. Read about the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) MySQL statement. Also read about the [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function.

Comment: *"but the form consists only of dropdowns and a date picker (no open fields)"* -- who says an attacker has to use the form in the web page to submit data to your website? Use prepared statements!

Comment: Thank you @axiac that is exactly what I needed. I will definitely be reading up more on all of this as I continue this project. I wish I had enough time to learn the ins and outs of mySQL in full before starting this but unfortunately it's a work obligation. Thanks again!